# SCSS: Fixed and fluid table-cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm building a div-list as a table with scss. I've converted it into css for the demonstartion.
The first and the last column is fixed with 90px and 30px.
The surrounded link is the table-row

| 90px | fluid sdfsdfsdfsdfd sd... | 30px |
| 90px | fluid  asdasdasd (blank)     | 30px |

The Table width should be 100%.
The width of the fluid part should get automatically 100% - 30px - 90px

My plan is to get the fluid width automatically depending on the fixed widths without

```
width: calc(100% - 30px - 90px)
```

The table should not be stretched greater than 100% and the content of the fluid container should be get the nice ellipsis tag.

Is there a mistake in my stylesheet?

```css
div.menu {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
div.menu .head {
  display: table-row;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
div.menu .head div {
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
}
div.menu .head div:first-of-type {
  width: 90px;
}
div.menu .head div:last-of-type {
  width: 30px;
}
div.menu a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: table-row;
  border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
div.menu a div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
div.menu a div:first-of-type {
  width: 90px;
}
div.menu a div:last-of-type {
  width: 30px;
}
div.menu a:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="head">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <div>Info</div>
    <div>Name of the item</div>
    <div>icon</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div>Info</div>
    <div>Name of another item</div>
    <div>icon</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div>Info</div>
    <div>This is a very long name, and it should not be greater than the page, and i want to see the icon. But it's not working.</div>
    <div>icon</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `table-layout: fixed;` solves the issue for me.

```
div.menu {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/1tv3ygka/

table-layout Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp